# Postgresql with BeautifulSoup insert data

Tags: python, postgresql, beautifulsoup

I want to insert data to the database PostreSQL. I created a table with 3 columns named:  title_list, article_list and author_list.

It's my code:

```
from link import post_title_list
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import psycopg2

HOST = "localhost"
USERNAME = "postgres"
PASSWORD = "root"
DATABASE = "data_db"

db = psycopg2.connect(host=HOST, user=USERNAME, password=PASSWORD, database=DATABASE)
cursor = db.cursor()

for url in post_title_list:
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

    for title in soup.find_all('h1',class_='post-title'):

    for article in soup.find_all(class_='post-content'):

    for author in soup.find_all(class_='author-name'):

db.commit()
```

In which way can I save the data to the table so that I can see for example:

```
title_list      article_list     author_list
First Title     Content          Author
Second Title    Second Content   Second Author
```

Answer (score 2):

You can insert all three types of values to three different lists and then insert it in case you assure content and author are present for all the titles.

> You can also use executemany() or mogrify() in case you want a quick operation

```
title_list = article_list = author_list = list()

for title in soup.find_all('h1',class_='post-title'):
    title_list.append(title)

for article in soup.find_all(class_='post-content'):
    article_list.append(article)

for author in soup.find_all(class_='author-name'):
    author_list.append(author)

for index in range(0, len(title_list)):
    title = title_list[index]
    article = article_list[index]
    author = author_list[index]

    postgres_insert_query = """ INSERT INTO your_table_name (title_list, article_list, author_list) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)"""
    record_to_insert = (title,article,author)
    cursor.execute(postgres_insert_query, record_to_insert)
```